# Angular Directive Wrap child Elements with ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I've been looking around but i couldn't find an answer so far.

Here is an example of what i want to do: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/YenU1z3gs0TMjK4rNofu

Here is my problem:

In the dataSlider directive i want to wrap all child elements

```
<div ng-repeat="dataSet in vm.dataList"></div>
```

with another div that has a ng-if

```
<div ng-if="something">
```

so that the directive can influence which children so display and which not.

Hope i managed to make myself clear. If i failed please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Solution I came up with:

```
/* @ngInject */
function Compile (tElement) {
    var children = tElement.children();
    children.attr('ng-if', '$index === vm.displayedList');
}
```